# Create loop for jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, loops, slideshow

Earlier I found a solution for a jquery slideshow on this site, but it is not looping. I tried to solve, but I need some help with it.

HTML:

```
            <div id="slideshow_header">
                 <ul class="slides_header">
                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/images/slideshow/01.jpg">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/images/slideshow/02.jpg">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/images/slideshow/03.jpg">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#slideshow_header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
}

ul.slides_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.slides_header li {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
}

ul.slides_header img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.active {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: fadein 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

JQUERY (need help here,  I'd like to make an if statement to loop the slideshow):

```
        $(function(){
        $('.slides_header li:first-child').addClass('active');
        $('.active').css({'z-index':'1'});
        });

        function slideSwitch() {                
            var $active = $('.slides_header li.active');
            var $next = $active.next();
            var $zindex = $active.css('z-index') + 1;

            // I'd like to make an if statement here to loop the slideshow
            console.log($next.length()); // <<< Tried to check if next not exists

            $next.addClass('active');
            $next.css({'z-index':$zindex});

            $active.removeClass('active');                  
            }

        $(function() {
            setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track trying to check the length of `$next`.

Try something like:

```
if(!$next.length){
   $next = $('.slides_header li').first();
   // or
   $next = $active.siblings().first();
}
```

Comment: Maybe in the future someone else will like to use this script, then make a parseInt on z-index variable:

var $zindex = parseInt($active.css('z-index')) + 1;

Then you won't get crazy z-index values.